# Where in my code can I put a meta tag for redirecting when using an else

Tags: php, html, sqlite

So I have a login page that I want to either take the user to the homepage or back the login page depending on whether they entered their details correctly.

```
<?php

    session_start();
unset($_SESSION['logerror']);
print_r($_POST);

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$db_name="website_database.sqlite"; // Database name
$tbl_name="User"; // Table name

$con= sqlite_open("Website_Database.sqlite");

// username and password sent from form
$username=$_POST['Username'];
$password=$_POST['Password'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE Username='".$username."' and Password='".$password."'";
$result= sqlite_query($con,$sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count= sqlite_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row


if($count==1){

// Register username, $password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("Username");
session_register("Password");
echo "Login Successful";
}
else {
echo "wrong username and password";
};
?>
```

I want to have something like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=login2.php">
```

To take the user back to the login page is unsuccessful. What would be the best way to place this in the if and elif ?

Comment: But how do I make it only do it based on if the user sucessfully logged in?

Comment: You will have to use `header('Location: ..);'` directive in PHP.

Comment: Use it with your conditional statement. Do you need example ?

Comment: @iamsleepy Yeah please that would be great

Comment: Ah, someone already put up an example. Check out what davidethell wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be better to use a Location header and redirect them that way rather than a meta refresh. If you want them to see the error just save error in a $_SESSION variable and check that on the new page.

```
else {
    $_SESSION['login_error'] = 'Wrong username or password.';
    session_write_close();
    header('Location: login2.php');
}
```

Then in your login2.php just check for the error:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['login_error'])) {
    echo "some html with the error: " . $_SESSION['login_error'];
}
```

Comment: Ah ok :) ty . But for some reason its telling me Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\www\Tutorials\sandbox\myfiles\checklogin.php:5) in Z:\www\Tutorials\sandbox\myfiles\checklogin.php on line 36

Comment: Great! Vote this up and mark it as the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to do it in the else, when the user is not logged correctly.

```
else {    
    header("Refresh: 5; URL = login2.php");    
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It's telling me Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\www\Tutorials\sandbox\myfiles\checklogin.php:5) in Z:\www\Tutorials\sandbox\myfiles\checklogin.php on line 36